# Rotated text on Chrome wobbles while animating

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a text element rotated -90 degrees that needs to translate left and right when the user clicks on it. For whatever reason, it wobbles while it is moving. I've only had this problem on Chrome.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g97bo56k/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('in').toggleClass('out');
    });
});
```

```css
.toggle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    
    top: 30px;
    
    transition: all 1s ease;

}

.toggle.in {
    margin-left: -38px
}
.toggle.out {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toggle in'>
    Click me
</div>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to make it a smoother animation?

Comment: I'm looking at this in Chrome and I also see a strange subtle wobble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
.toggle {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

No more wobble!

http://jsfiddle.net/g97bo56k/2/

Comment: Excellent! Here's some more info in case you're interested: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/